# How do I pass a value from cc.net to build-script? ccnet.config->xx.build

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have various settings in my ccnet.config file and wish to pass them to my build file in order to keep these constants in one place.

How do I do that?!

Thanks,

Anders, Denmark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your build file is a NAnt file, you would do it like this:

```
<nant>
    <buildFile>xx.build</buildFile>
    <buildArgs>-D:foo="$(foo)" -D:bar="$(bar)"</buildArgs>
    ...
</nant>
```

You can access the variable in the build script via `${foo}` resp. `${bar}` then.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be something wrong with your setup, because I'm using

```
<buildArgs>-D:publishroot="$(publish-directory)"</buildArgs>
```

and NAnt sees this as expected. Does the value of the variable contain spaces? I had problems with this before.